# Adding computed column to EF 4.0 Model

Tags: entity-framework-4

I want to add an association to an EF 4.0 model that uses two constant properties as part of what would be the referential constraint.  Obviously it's no good adding the properties into the partial class of the entity as these won't be seen by the EF designer when defining the association.  So, is it possible to add a computed column to the mode that returns say a constant varchar 'ABC', etc and then use that column as part of the association?

Many thanks,

Lee.

Answer (score 0):

Would your DB allow this? I don't think DBs typically let you define a FK constraint on a computed column. You should make all EF associations reflect actual DB constraints.

Comment: There are no constraints in the DB, only in the model. Basically we have table A that has a bcode column and table B that has a code, code1 and code2 column.  Code1 and Code2 in table B have various vales amongst which code1 will have 'AA' and code2 'BB' defined by the legacy application. Code in table B also has various values. I need an association from table A -> B where A.bcode = B.code and b.code1 = 'AA' and b.code2 = 'BB'. I thought if I added two computed fields in table a that were called bcode1 and bcode2 with values AA and BB respectively I'd be able to add the association?

Comment: No constraints in the DB = not right. EF relationships are a reflection of DB constraints, not a substitute for them.

Comment: We can't change the db schema (3rd party app) and the EF model is surely a logical representation of the db (our coding model).  In fact we don't want it to look anything like the fully normalised db schema.  All of our associations are modelled in the edmx and work fine apart from the one in question.  I guess it's more a question of computed fields in the model.